# Google Compute Engine: doing chmod -R 777 /home/user blocks SSH access?

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, chmod, google-cloud-platform

I am trying to setup multiple users on a Google Cloud Instance running Ubuntu 18.04. One of the steps I do, `sudo chmod -R 777 /home/user`  blocks future ssh connexions to the instance, with message:

> Permission denied (publickey). ERROR: (gcloud.compute.ssh)
>   [/usr/bin/ssh] exited with return code [255]

I am not sure where the problem is?

1. Is doing `sudo chmod -R 770 /home/user` wrong per se? What I am trying to do follows the lines of [this post](https://yuhuisdatascienceblog.blogspot.com/2017/07/setting-up-r-studio-server-on-google.html), so actually there are more steps involved, but the `chmod` step seems the one creating trouble
2. Or is that an issue at the GC/ssh level?

#### Code to reproduce the problem

replace `user_name` with your own user name:

```
gcloud compute instances create DEMO --image-family ubuntu-1804-lts --image-project ubuntu-os-cloud  --machine-type n1-standard-8 --zone us-west1-b

## ssh connexion DOES work:
gcloud compute ssh user_name@DEMO --zone us-west1-b

# now do:
sudo chmod --recursive 777 /home/user_name

## ssh connexion DOES NOT work:
gcloud compute ssh user_name@DEMO --zone us-west1-b

# delete this instance
gcloud compute instances delete DEMO
```

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45155619/gcloud-compute-ssh-refuses-connection-return-code-255

Comment: It is because private keys and such in `~/.ssh/*` must not be readable by other users on the system... otherwise I could copy your private key, or in the case of 777 permissions just add my own key to the `authorized_keys` file.

Comment: thanks @ivanivan, that seems to make a lot of sense. Are you suggesting I should use something like `770` instead, or simply do chown excluding `.ssh/*`? Thanks!

Comment: I would do `chmod 700 ~/.ssh` and `chmod 600 ~/.ssh/*`  If you are on a shared system, and there are no processes owned by others that need to get to your home directory (ie, apache serviing http://example.com/~username from ~/public_html) I would have your home directory and most of the ones in it as `750`

Comment: Mmh, apparently even this won't help, I did something like `$sudo chmod --recursive 770 /home/user
$sudo chmod 700 ~/.ssh
$sudo chmod 600 ~/.ssh/*` then could not connect anymore *Permission denied (publickey).* Maybe I should try to avoid touching .ssh at all. Also I should mention I do other manipulations like adding a group, and assigning my user to that group.